# Configuring GAE Remote API on the Server

Tags: google-app-engine, web.xml, remoteapi

The introduction to Remote API for Java at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi runs fine but I just get  404 errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: can't get appId from remote api; status code = 404, body: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Not Found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL <code>/remote_api</code> was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I believe this to be because the server is not configured correctly. The instructions in the section ‘Configuring Remote API on the Server’ are too vague for me – beginner. 
The statement ‘add the following to your web.xml’ is the problem. I am not sure which web.xml this statement refers to. Putting web.xml in various obvious places eg war/WEB-INF/web.xml doesn’t seem to help. Also tried this as a Dynamic Web project (in Eclipse) with the xml code in WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml , which also doesn’t help.

Looks like a basic misunderstanding of the structure of a Java project that uses Remote API but can’t see the way forward. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, that it's a one-module application, the *web.xml* file is located directly in the directory *war/WEB-INF*.

You could build a full sample application for Google App Engine by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction).

Also the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) would create a similar sample app for you.